# Load xlsx file into Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Is there any way to load .xlsx files into Pig? I need to perform an operation in PIG using the excel file [.xlsx] as input, but i couldn't find any built-in functions available for this purpose.?

Any help to achieve this would be appreciable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

First convert the xlsx file into csv then do the following,

```
REGISTER Location\to\piggybank.jar

Data = load 'Location\to\csv\file' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') as (col1,col2,..);
```

It (CSVExcelStorage) worked for me. Hope it works.

Comment: Could use a note on how to convert xlsx to csv. Note that I believe this is not possible with pig directly.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if your excel  has only one sheet then you can try to use CSVExcelStorage

How to use? check for pig example in below link

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html

Comment: CSVExcelStorage doesn't work for the .xlsx file format. I used the below codes  REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
a = LOAD '/path/to/file.xlsx' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('\t')
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1;
DUMP b; but it doesn't dumped the results as expected.

Comment: What does the xlsx file have, If CSVExcelStorage handler does not work then you should implement a storage handler.This was the closest storagehandler that I could see in Pig's javadoc https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/package-tree.html