# How to Convert XLSX file to CSV file in PIG?

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig, xlsx, apache-pig-grunt

How can we `covert a xlsx` file to `csv` file using PIG SCRIPT.
I found that there is CSVExcelStorage to store alredy converted xlsx to csv file.

```
STORE x INTO '<destFileName>'
USING CSVExcelStorage(['<delimiter>' [,{'YES_MULTILINE' | 'NO_MULTILINE'} [,{'UNIX' | 'WINDOWS' | 'UNCHANGED'}]]]);
Eg:

STORE res INTO '/tmp/result.csv'
USING CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'WINDOWS');
```

I think before that we need to covert the xlsx file into csv.

So how can we do that using pig.

Any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load xlsx file into Pig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400372/load-xlsx-file-into-pig)

Answer (score -1):

Refer: [CSVExcelStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html)

Usage:

```
STORE x INTO '<destFileName>'
USING CSVExcelStorage(['<delimiter>' [,{'YES_MULTILINE' | 'NO_MULTILINE'} [,{'UNIX' | 'WINDOWS' | 'UNCHANGED'}]]]);
```

Eg:

```
STORE res INTO '/tmp/result.csv'
USING CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'WINDOWS');
```

where CRLF is line break characters (0x0d 0x0a: \r\n) and comma is field separator.

Comment: I think it is for storing the csv file. But before that we have to convert the xlsx file into csv right.                                                                   I want to covert the xlsx file into csv file using pig.Just like xml file to csv using PIG...[link]https://acadgild.com/blog/converting-xml-into-csv-using-pig/...I want to convert a xlsx file to csv. any suggestions

Comment: This does indeed not convert an xlsx into a csv. As you can see from the link that you added, it loads a CSV (with the formatting standards that excel uses when making a csv). As described in the question that I linked, pig cannot read xlsx files directly.